# Can I see badges for a specific technology?

Tags: support, badges

Is it possible to show technology wise badges? Suppose I earn  some badges on [android](/questions/tagged/android) and some on [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone), then how we know technology wise badges?

I know one way to click on badges and know on which question you earn this badge. But any 
easy way ?

Comment: @bol - Wouldn't "tag-badges" be a better fit here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - you can earn ["tag" badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags).  They look like this :

[image: 123]

- For a bronze badge - Earned 100 upvotes for at least 20 answers
- For a silver badge - Earned 400 upvotes for at least 80 answers
- for a gold badge   - Earned 1000 upvotes for at least 200 answers

The badge you see in the screen shot is a bronze badge for the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag (on meta), but the same goes for **any** tag on any site - including all the technology tags on the main Stack Overflow site :

- [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)
- [php](/questions/tagged/php)
- [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)
- [ook](/questions/tagged/ook)
- [android](/questions/tagged/android)
- [pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal)
- [logo](/questions/tagged/logo)
- [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone)
- [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)
- [waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles)
- [and-many-many-more](/questions/tagged/and-many-many-more)...

You can earn these badges for **any** tag.  Believe it or not - even for the "status completed" tag :)

[image]